# Development approches for Blackberry playbook

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I am new on development of Blackberry playbook apps. Can we develop whole apps using HTML5,CSS,Javascript ?
Can we develope apps using Java for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code whole apps using standard web technologies (HTML5/CSS/JavaScript) - for this, u should take a look at the link to the **WebWorks SDK** at http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/ (here, also the second approach for app development, namely using Adobe AIR, is mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Java - not yet, because both BB OS and Android SDKs haven't been released yet